# iOS Putting White Bar on Website

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad, web

I've tried a couple things, but nothing has fixed my issue. On iOS, a white bar is showing to right of the site cutting off some of the content. Help?

http://qusik.com/newsite/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I rechecked your site, your ipad image and its container is way more wider than your other containers, try to reduce its size to 960-940 width

Comment: Thank You! It's still there, but much smaller.

Comment: Any suggestions for getting rid of the existing white?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing that white-space due to the fact that your content is overflowing your viewport as the page is shrunken on your tablet/mobile device, one way to fix it would be to remove that background image and color from your `header` and creating a `.bg` div with it instead and positioning it absolutely (stretching it in all directions, e.g. `top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;`),  relative to the body so it will stretch in all directions in your screen, like so:

```
.bg {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url("images/tint_blue.png");
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
    z-index:-1; /* to place it behind everything else, just make sure not to have bg colors on your page elements */
}
```

Another (while very unorthodox) method is to place your bg image and color on the `html` tag instead, like so:

```
html {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url("images/tint_blue.png");
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```